# Display row values in one string in android using sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I've managed to get all rows of an sqlite table in android. However, I want to display all these rows in just one string. How will I do that? This is my code:

```
 DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(checklist.this);
                            int cnt = db.CountMessageProduct("0");
                            Log.d("productcnt", String.valueOf(cnt));
                            List<Product> product = db.getAllProduct();


                            String b;
                                for (Product p : product) {
                                   b = p.getStorCode() + "/" + p.getCode() + 
"/" + p.getBstock() + "/" + p.getDeliveries() + "/" + p.getSpoilage() + "/" + p.getEstock() + ",";
                                    Log.d("txt",b);
                                }
```

Logcat

```
08-19 10:29:09.202  15782-15782/? D/txt﹕ TGIG/C4/2/3/4/5,
08-19 10:29:09.203  15782-15782/? D/txt﹕ RBSN/C1/12/3/3/4,
08-19 10:29:09.203  15782-15782/? D/txt﹕ MKTI/C10/23/45/67/89,
08-19 10:29:09.203  15782-15782/? D/txt﹕ RBSN/C1/12/3/4/56,
08-19 10:29:09.203  15782-15782/? D/txt﹕ TGIG/C10/46/8/9/0,
```

Desired Output:

```
TGIG/C4/2/3/4/5,RBSN/C1/12/3/3/4,MKTI/C10/23/45/67/89,RBSN/C1/12/3/4/56,TGIG/C10/46/8/9/0,
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the language you're using.

Comment: Hello, just do b = b + your string... and after for loop print log so you will get desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The comments answered your question but here is the exact code.

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(checklist.this);
                        int cnt = db.CountMessageProduct("0");
                        Log.d("productcnt", String.valueOf(cnt));
                        List<Product> product = db.getAllProduct();


                        String b;
                            for (Product p : product) {
                               b = b + p.getStorCode() + "/" + p.getCode() + 
"/" + p.getBstock() + "/" + p.getDeliveries() + "/" + p.getSpoilage() + "/" + p.getEstock() + ",";
                            }
Log.d("txt",b);
```